# Cmake Gtest project exe exits with errorcode 255

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, exe, googletest

I have been using a number of c++ projects for gtest unit cases. While all these were executing fine all these years, now after updating the openssl version 1.1.1a, seeing some strange problem. Bilt in VS2017

the test project exe is not executing or not starting at all. I tried executing the exe from a command prompt. It just comes out of the execution immediately without any execution or message. It is not taking or considering any argument like --shuffle-tests.

I tried adding trace cout logs in main function but still its has no effect.

The error i get is

```
6: Test command: plugin-tests.exe "--gtest_shuffle" "--gtest_output=xml:TESTS-plugin.xml"
6: Test timeout computed to be: 10000000
6/8 Test #6: plugin-tests ...........***Failed    0.01 sec
```

I am helpless in debugging in the gtest exe as there are no proper documentation for this as well.

Could any body please shed some light on this ?

It has the standard GTest functions to init and runn all tests. This has been working all these years.

The change i made in the code is,

Modified 
EVP_CIPHER_CTX m_context_encrypt
to
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *m_context_encrypt
and did
m_context_encrypt = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()

as per the structure changes in openssl1.1 onwards.

And, the openssl is statically linked to the project exe which required two of the windows libraries to be linked with

crypt32 ws2_32

so added those dependency the cmake like,

```
if( WIN32 ) 
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} crypt32 ws2_32)
endif()
```

The gtest unit test cases are executing successfully in linux build.
The problem is with the windows execution.

However out of 8 test projects, one test project is able to execute properly in windows, and i find no difference in the cmake files.

It is kindof strange

Note: Exit code of the exe seems to be 255

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @frp Added some more information in the question. Would that help ?

Comment: By any chance, don't you have any advanced logic in singleton classes/static variables initialization? It might be them crashing the application even before it gets to `main`. You should try staring the problematic binaries under VS debugger to investigate it.

Comment: Try running the test binaries directly from a terminal.  This might give you more information that's being printed to standard error.

Comment: @StephenNewell Tried running the test binary in a cmd. Doesn't execute anything, just comes out of it. Added cout logs in main, yet nothing printed.

Comment: @R2RT having trouble debugging the application with VS 2017 as there are some known issues. Working on it now :(